# Удалить тег <a>..</a>. Регулярные выражения

Tags: python-3.x

Есть html код, надо из текса убрать тег ...

Пример(исходный вариант):

```html
<p><strong>Мощный Фонарь Police BL-Q2822- 30000W T6,  12V под руж. два диода</strong></p><p> </p><p> </p><p><strong>  Тактический фонарь Police 12V BL-Q2822- 30000W T6</strong> мощный фонарь имеющий два отражателя для еще более эфективного и яркого свечения. В <a href="/g9893677-komplektuyuschie">комплекте</a> идет универсальное крепление под ружье, выносная кнопка, два аккумулятора 18650
```

Конечный вариант:

```html
<p><strong>Мощный Фонарь Police BL-Q2822- 30000W T6,  12V под руж. два диода</strong></p><p> </p><p> </p><p><strong>  Тактический фонарь Police 12V BL-Q2822- 30000W T6</strong> мощный фонарь имеющий два отражателя для еще более эфективного и яркого свечения. В комплекте идет универсальное крепление под ружье, выносная кнопка, два аккумулятора 18650
```

Хочу находить подобные ссылки с помощью регулярных выражений, но чет не могу составить это регулярное выражение, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо !

Comment: Можно просто взять [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) и не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: обязательное чтение: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4279)

Comment: Пробовал использовать bleach, но чет не пойму как правильно с ним работать.. может кто-то показать пример ? я делаю примерно так 
`   q=bleach.clean(html_text, tags=['a'])`
и полагаю что теги <a> должны исчезнуть, но получаю ошибку '**TypeError: argument cannot be of 'Tag' type, must be of text type**'

Comment: связанный вопрос [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/753052/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Регулярные выражения могут легко сломаться](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94528/4279), используйте html парсер для работы с html. Чтобы распаковать `<a>` элементы (убрать теги, оставить содержимое):

```
import bs4  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    a.unwrap()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так можно.

```python
import re
html = '<p><strong>Мощный Фонарь Police BL-Q2822- 30000W T6,  12V под руж. два диода</strong></p><p> </p><p> </p><p><strong>  Тактический фонарь Police 12V BL-Q2822- 30000W T6</strong> мощный фонарь имеющий два отражателя для еще более эфективного и яркого свечения. В <a href="/g9893677-komplektuyuschie">комплекте</a> идет универсальное крепление под ружье, выносная кнопка, два аккумулятора 18650'
notag = re.sub("<a.*?>|</a>", "", html)
```

Comment: это не работает, если [`>` встретится в атрибуте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94528/4279)